# Unit testing NETPortable library in Mono

Tags: mono, nunit, monodevelop

I just started a mono project that has a server and a client. The plan is to contain all code common between the server and the client in a .NET Portable Library, so I don't have to re-implement things... However, I can't find a decent way to unit test my library.

Monodevelop don't let me add nunit test fixtures directly to the project, so instead I created a new empty project, which I add all my nunit test fixtures to. This project references the library. The problem comes when referencing System.Net.Sockets in both my portable library, and the test project. I get an error, probably due to the fact that the portable library uses a diffrent profile/framework than my test project...

What is the best way to add unit tests to my portable library? :/

Comment: Sounds like a bug in MonoDevelop or Mono. Did you check the existing bug reports? http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs

Comment: I think it has something to do with nunit not being available for the same framework/profile... The same reason why nunit is not being available for MonoDroid